# Custom Dialog for Hockeyapp on Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, crash-reports, hockeyapp

The `Hockeyapp SDK` for `iOS` allows to set a custom `AlertView` that is shown when `Hockeyapp` wants to send a crash. 
I was wondering if there is a similar way to do this on `Android`? I could not find a related method in hockey documentation that would take my custom Dialog.

`iOS` documentation for `setAlertViewHandler`:
http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/3.6.1/docs/docs/HowTo-Set-Custom-AlertViewHandler.html

Comment: This is not possible. Please contact HockeyApp support at http://support.hockeyapp.net/ for related questions. Thanks.